# Yodlee: What possible acctType values exist?

Tags: yodlee

For the getItemSummariesForSite API, could you please provide a list of every possible type returnable in the "acctType" field.

(Basically, I need a foolproof way to know if it is a debit-type or credit-type of account)

Thanks

Comment: Let me know if provided information is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following data describes Account types supported by Bank, Insurance and Investment containers.

```
Bank Account Type

Type ID AccountTypes
1   unknown
2   other
3   checking
4   savings
7   moneyMarket
8   ira
9   401k
16  charge
25  CD
72  ppf
73  CMA
77  accountsPayable
78  accountsReceivable
79  association
80  cash
81  costOfGoodsSold
Bill Account Type

Type ID AccountTypes
19  telephone
20  utility
21  cable
22  card
23  insurance
24  wireless
Card Account Type

Type ID AccountTypes
1   unknown
2   other
15  credit
16  charge
22  card
70  prepaid
71  storeCard
Loan Account Type

Loan Type ID    Loan Types
1   Unknown
2   loan
3   Mortgage
4   Installment
5   Personal
6   HomeEquityLineOfCredit
7   LineOfCredit
8   Auto
9   Student
10  Other
Tax

Type ID AccountTypes
62  Tax
Payment Service

Type ID AccountTypes
18  paymentOnlyService
22  card
Investment Account Type

Type ID AccountTypes
1   unknown
2   other
5   brokerageCash
6   brokerageMargin
7   moneyMarket
8   ira
9   401k
10  403b
11  trust
12  annuity
13  simple
14  custodial
26  brokerageCashOption
27  brokerageMarginOption
30  jttic
31  jtwros
35  roth
36  rothConversion
37  rollover
39  529Plan
40  457DeferredCompensation
41  401a
42  psp
43  mpp
44  stockBasket
45  livingTrust
46  revocableTrust
47  irrevocableTrust
48  charitableRemainder
49  charitableLead
50  charitableGiftAccount
51  sep
52  utma
53  ugma
54  esopp
55  administrator
56  executor
57  partnership
58  soleProprietorShip
60  investmentClub
61  restrictedStockAward
32  communityProperty
33  jointByEntirety
34  conservatorShip
38  educational
59  church
74  employeeStockPurchasePlan
73  CMA
75  performancePlan
76  brokerageLinkAccount
```

Please refer to this [link](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Yodlee_Account_Types). Here you'll find all the account types which you could receive in "acctType" field.